# cmake execute_process COMMAND

Tags: bash, cmake

CMakeList.txt:

```
set(MAKE_CMD "${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/makeHeaders.sh ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR} ${INC_DIR}")
MESSAGE("COMMAND: ${MAKE_CMD}")
execute_process(COMMAND "${MAKE_CMD}"   
   RESULT_VARIABLE CMD_ERROR
   OUTPUT_FILE CMD_OUTPUT)
MESSAGE( STATUS "CMD_ERROR:" ${CMD_ERROR})
MESSAGE( STATUS "CMD_OUTPUT:" ${CMD_OUTPUT})
```

cmake .. OUTPUT:

```
COMMAND: /home/src/makeHeaders.sh /home/src /home/include
-- CMD_ERROR:No such file or directory
-- CMD_OUTPUT:
```

If I copy the COMMAND that cmake prints out above, paste it on the command line, it works fine

Here makeHeaders.sh

```
#!/bin/bash
echo In makeHeaders.sh
echo first: $1
echo second $2
echo Making fxsizec.h
echo grep VERSION $1/config/6/cfs.c | grep '^#define' | grep -v 'PGM_V' > $2/fxsizec.h  
echo Making fxsizeo.h
echo grep VERSION $1/opaid/WRS.c | grep '^#define' | grep -v 'PGM_V' |awk '{print $$1 " OA"$$2 " "$$3}' > $2/fxsizeo.h

grep VERSION $1/config/6/cfs.c | grep '^#define' | grep -v 'PGM_V' > $2/fxsizec.h  
grep VERSION $1/opaid/WRS.c | grep '^#define' | grep -v 'PGM_V' |awk '{print $$1 " OA"$$2 " "$$3}' > $2/fxsizeo.h
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Don't set the args as part of your command variable. You can pass them in `execute_process`:

```
set(MAKE_CMD "${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/makeHeaders.sh")
MESSAGE("COMMAND: ${MAKE_CMD} ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR} ${INC_DIR}")
execute_process(COMMAND ${MAKE_CMD} ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR} ${INC_DIR}
   RESULT_VARIABLE CMD_ERROR
      OUTPUT_FILE CMD_OUTPUT)
  MESSAGE( STATUS "CMD_ERROR:" ${CMD_ERROR})
  MESSAGE( STATUS "CMD_OUTPUT:" ${CMD_OUTPUT})
```

**EDIT**
In adition to the above answer, if you want to add the arguments to the command variable you can do it like so:

```
set(MAKE_CMD "${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/makeHeaders.sh")
list(APPEND MAKE_CMD ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR})
```

Comment: THANK YOU.  That worked.  Any idea why moving the args solved that?  It seems like it should have worked the other way too.

Comment: CMake executes the child process using operating system APIs directly. There's no intermediate shell used. So when you pass the command with args as a single argument, it tries to execute that first argument as if that was the process's name, it doesn't expand and concat like a shell script would.

Comment: I have `cmake version 3.13.4` and the above, and other of my anti-parallelization or attemp to sequentialize this has failed , file not found error.  Of the `cmake` that I have, there is no way to sequentialize it.... i think this is a bug.